# VueJS filterBy with dynamic argument

Tags: vue.js

I have a VueJS object with data that looks like the following:

```
phases: [
  { id: 1, ... },
  { id: 2, ... },
  { id: 3, ... },
],
roles: [
  { phaseId: 1, title: "Account Manager" },
  { phaseId: 1, title: "Creative Director" },
  { phaseId: 2, title: "Account Manager" },
  { phaseId: 2, title: "Creative Director" },
]
```

And my v-for loop looks like the following:

```
    <article v-for="phase in phases" class="phase">

        ... Other content ...

        <div v-for="role in roles | filterBy phase.id in 'phaseId' ">
            <p>${role.title}</p>
        </div>
    </article>
```

I'm trying to filter the roles array to only show roles with the "parent" phase given by the ID. Since the `roles` for-loop will be running multiple times, each time it will only show the appropriate roles.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Filters are deprecated please don't use them

Answer (score 3):

+1 @gurghet, filters are deprecated.

Use a `method`

```
data: {
  phases: [
    { id: 1, ... },
    { id: 2, ... },
    { id: 3, ... },
  ],
  roles: [
    { phaseId: 1, title: "Account Manager" },
    { phaseId: 1, title: "Creative Director" },
    { phaseId: 2, title: "Account Manager" },
    { phaseId: 2, title: "Creative Director" },
  ]
},
methods: {
  filtered(id){
    return this.roles.filter(rol => rol.phaseId === id)
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<article v-for="phase in phases" class="phase">
  ... Other content ...
  <div v-for="role in filtered(phase.id) ">
    <p>${role.title}</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

[Exmaple](https://fiddle.jshell.net/7a892vm5/)

Answer (score 0):

***One can use a mixin that calls the actual filter***

***1. First we need to register a filter globally***

```
Vue.filter('normalizetext', function (value) {
  if (!value) return '';
  value = value.toString();
  value = value.replace('_', ' ').toLowerCase();
  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
})
```

***2.Create a mixin***

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
  /**
   * The methods that the mixin used for filer functions.
   */
  methods: {
    /**
     * Method used to check if specific element is found in an filer
     *
     * @param {filer} filtername filer to find created filter
     *
     * @returns {any} filtered output
     */
    dynamicFilter(filterName, value) {
      return Vue.filter(filterName)(value);
    }
  }
};
```

***3.Calling filter***

```
    <template>
      {{
        dynamicFilter(data.FilterName, value)
      }}
    </template>
```